# What is the cleanest way to create an instance of a model that belongs_to <parent_model>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I am pretty sure there is and answer out there.. But I can't seem to find what is the cleanest way to do it, and I am just starting playing around with Ruby and Rails 3.1.

I have a Client model and a Project model.

I'd like to have a button on the client#show view that leads to a project#new where there is no need to input the client_id.

Furthermore the project#new should still be accessible on his own and ask for the client_id if it is not available.

Any help appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at nested resources:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Using that take care of the passing through of the parent ID.  You can have a route that goes directly to project#new as well and then you'll just need to handle whether to ask for the client ID in the view depending on whether it is already defined.

Comment: Mhhh are you sure it is the cleaniest way? What happens for children and subchildren of project? Shall I keep nesting? I managed to send the the ckient id as a query parameter, but doesn't look very nice either.

Comment: No, don't keep nesting.  Best practices say that you shouldn't nest more than two deep.  If you think about it there's no reason to nest deeply.  In a hierarchy you only need the direct parent eg:  `/client/4/project/new` which creates a project with ID 5 and then `project/5/task/new`

Comment: I honestly think that if you keep your nesting shallow it's a clean way to handle this.  The path helpers end up being really clean: `new_client_project_path(@client.id)`

Comment: I didn't think it this way, cool I'll give it a shot! Thanks mate.